# how can i implement a "like" button?

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

i need to implement a like button The logic that I look for is that when you click, the color is changed the button and when you click again, you have the same color again

i used this

```
  // LIKE
            viewHolder.shakaLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(viewHolder.shakaLike.isChecked()) {
                        Drawable myLike = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nuevo_arrow_verde);
                        viewHolder.shakaLike.setBackgroundDrawable(myLike);


                        Drawable myLikeM = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.middleblack);
                        viewHolder.middleFinger.setBackgroundDrawable(myLikeM);

                        onLikeClick(model.getPostId());
                    }else if (!viewHolder.shakaLike.isChecked()){
                        Drawable m = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nuevo_arrow_blanco);
                        viewHolder.shakaLike.setBackgroundDrawable(m);
                    }

                }
            });
```

but doesnt works
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your method inverts the boolean you are using in your if check. So if it's not already liked (liked =false) then do set liked to equal true because now it is liked, and set the arrow to green background.

```
viewHolder.shakaLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!liked) {
           liked = true; //because it wasn't liked(default state at start), but it was clicked to make it liked
           viewHolder.middleFinger.setBackgroundDrawable(green);
        } else if (liked){
            liked = false; //because it was liked and was clicked to unlike
            viewHolder.shakaLike.setBackgroundDrawable(white);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: how can i implement this in a setOnClickLisenter()

Comment: Initialize the variable as a member variable, outside the OnClickListener. Then get a reference to your buttonView. Next apply buttonView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener) { public void onClick(View v) {//if statements goes here}}

Comment: I redid the original post. does that help more. You can use "liked" as either a member variable of the activity or as a shared preference and it will use the last value between closing and reopening the app.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
Drawable green = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nuevo_arrow_verde);
Drawable white = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.nuevo_arrow_blanco);

boolean liked = false;

viewHolder.shakaLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicked = !clicked;
                if(liked) {
                   viewHolder.middleFinger.setBackgroundDrawable(green);
                } else if (!viewHolder.shakaLike.isChecked()){
                    viewHolder.shakaLike.setBackgroundDrawable(white);
                }


            }
        });
```